# Check if values of datetime column in df2 is within datateime values of df1 in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a 2 dataframes like this:

**df1**

```
ID <- c("A","B","A","C","C","B","B","A")
StartDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:00:13", "2015-09-29 05:55:50", "2015-09-29 11:45:14", "2015-09-29 15:24:00",
                               "2015-09-29 17:24:12", "2015-09-29 21:34:31", "2015-09-29 22:22:22", "2015-09-29 23:38:22") 
EndDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:13:56", "2015-09-29 06:13:50", "2015-09-29 12:23:14", "2015-09-29 15:58:00",
                             "2015-09-29 17:58:17", "2015-09-29 22:06:31", "2015-09-29 22:52:28", "2015-09-29 23:55:22") 
MEASUREMENT <- c("Length","Length","Width","Length","Width","Height","Length","Height") 
df1 <- data.frame(ID,StartDatetime,EndDatetime,MEASUREMENT)
```

**df2**

```
ID <- c("A","B","A","C","C","B","B")
MStart <- c("09/29/2015 00:02:13", "09/29/2015 05:56:50", "09/30/2015 11:55:14", "09/29/2015 15:33:00",
                    "09/29/2015 17:28:12", "09/29/2015 21:30:31", "09/29/2015 22:26:22") 
MEnd <- c("09/29/2015 00:11:12", "09/29/2015 06:55:50", "09/30/2015 11:54:14", "09/29/2015 15:47:00",
                  "09/29/2015 17:44:12", "09/29/2015 22:02:31", "09/29/2015 22:44:22") 
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Width","Length","Width","Height","Length") 
df2 <- data.frame(ID,MStart,MEnd,Measurement)
```

I am trying to solve an interesting problem of checking if the ID's having the MStart & MEnd in df2 are within the date time ranges in df1 for every measurement. The logic retuns

```
TRUE if (MStart & MEnd) **is within** (StartDatetime & EndDatetime)
FALSE if (MStart & MEnd) **is not within** (StartDatetime & EndDatetime)
```

My Desired output will be df3 with all the columns in df1 and also add a column with True or False values.

**df3**

```
  ID       StartDatetime         EndDatetime MEASUREMENT True_False
1  A 2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:13:56      Length       TRUE
2  B 2015-09-29 05:55:50 2015-09-29 06:13:50      Length      FALSE
3  A 2015-09-29 11:55:14 2015-09-29 12:23:14       Width      FALSE
4  C 2015-09-29 15:24:00 2015-09-29 15:58:00      Length       TRUE
5  C 2015-09-29 17:24:12 2015-09-29 17:58:17       Width       TRUE
6  B 2015-09-29 21:34:31 2015-09-29 22:06:31      Height      FALSE
7  B 2015-09-29 22:22:22 2015-09-29 22:52:28      Length       TRUE
8  A 2015-09-29 23:38:22 2015-09-29 23:55:22      Height      FALSE
```

I am stuck at this error when trying to convert the date format of df2 and not able to move forward.

```
**df2$MStart <- as.POSIXct(df2$MStart,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")**

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Please guide me on how I could solve this problem. I am trying to use dplyr or data.table for solving this but not knowing the logic for working with date times.

**EDIT**
 I just made an edit and removed the last row of df2 and hence it has only 7 rows now. I want to address this case as well since my bigger dataset contains more rows in df1 and fewer rows in df2 and hence would like to return those unmatched rows with FALSE from df1 as well.

Comment: Thank you for organizing your question with reproducible data, an explanation of what you want, what you've tried, and your desired output. Is it Friday the 13th or something? Oh yes it is :)

Comment: lol yes it is indeed :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1_fix = 
  df1 %>%
  mutate(StartDatetime = ymd_hms(StartDatetime),
         EndDatetime = ymd_hms(EndDatetime)) %>%
  rename(Measurement = MEASUREMENT)


df2_fix = 
  df2 %>%
  mutate(MStart  = mdy_hms(MStart),
         MEnd = mdy_hms(MEnd))

initial_join = 
  df1_fix %>%
  full_join(df2_fix)

initial_join %>%
  filter(StartDatetime < EndDatetime,
         MStart < MEnd) %>%
  mutate(test = 
           int_overlaps(
             interval(StartDatetime, EndDatetime),
               interval(MStart, MEnd) ) ) %>%
  right_join(initial_join) %>%
  mutate(test = test %in% TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it gives me an error "Error: No common variables. Please specify `by` param." Is the by = ID missing in this? and I need the measurement grouping with the datetimes as well. Could you please check that?

Comment: left_join should pick up on common variables automatically. It lOoks loke both datasets have a "ID" and "Measurement" variable. I've added a rename to decapitalize MEASUREMENT

Comment: Fantastic. It works well now. While I was working on my bigger dataset, I realized my Rows of df1 > rows of df2. It throws an error. Is there any way your solution can handle that? I would ideally like to return the row in df1 that doesn't have a matching with a FALSE in TRUE_FALSE column. Please let me know if this is not clear. I have modified my question too for you to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
df1$interval <- interval(ymd_hms(df1$StartDatetime),ymd_hms(df1$EndDatetime))
df2$interval <- interval(mdy_hms(df2$MStart),mdy_hms(df1$MEnd))
df1$True_False <- ifelse((df1$interval > df2$interval), "TRUE", "FALSE")
df1
```

Comment: Hi. You logic seems work for most part of it but the  3rd row should have false because the date time is out of range in df1. Please check it and I would like to know if "interval" logic holds better than the other methods

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, which is similar to bramtayl's solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df<-df1
df$StartDatetime <- ymd_hms(StartDatetime)
df$EndDatetime <- ymd_hms(EndDatetime)
df$MStart<- mdy_hms(MStart)
df$MEnd<- mdy_hms(MEnd)

df3 <- df%>%
  mutate(True_False = ifelse(MStart >StartDatetime & MStart <EndDatetime &MEnd >StartDatetime & MEnd <EndDatetime,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Comment: Could you explain how df$MStart <- mdy_hms(MStart) works? I see that df <- df1 and df1 doesn't have the MStart column. I am confused here. It is working but want to understand how that works. When I applied the logic to my larger dataset it says the "undefined columns, object not found"

Comment: df$MStart  is creating a new column in the df dataframe called 'MStart', it is then populating this new column with the values from mdy_hms(MStart). You can do this with any values you like (e.g. df$test <-1 will create a column called 'test' full of 1s).

Comment: But how can it populate values from df2? I see that you are specifying df <- df1, which means df should only look for values in df1. I am missing any lines of code that allows values in df2 to be taken in df? How does df know  to pull MStart from df2? Sorry if I am confusing you. I like you solution and it works for this problem but it isn't working on my bigger dataset.

Comment: No problem, your example had MStart existing as a separate vector before it was added into df2 (my code should follow directly after the code you gave previously). Do you expect df1 and df2 to contain exactly the same items in each row? If so, you can do df$MStart <- mdy_hms(df2$MStart).

Comment: I got your point. I just realized the rows aren't exactly the same and that is what is causing the issue. Could you help me overcome that. My df1 in a bigger dataset is 614 rows and df2 is 451 rows. How can we modify this?

Comment: I just made an edit to post to address the issue of differing rows in df1 and df2.